# Angular controller service promise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I want to wait for an http response before exiting angular controller. I have written the following code. But id doesn't work as the controller still exits before the http call is returned. Can anyone help me out to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('MyService', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('/api/endpoint').then(function(res){
          return res.data;
        });
    });

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
  MyService.then(function(data){
    $scope.myVarialbe = data;
  })
}]);
```

Comment: Check you console log for errors

Comment: no errors in the console. checked.

Comment: Hi, I recreated your scenario using $timeout instead of $http. I am getting the intended results. Please refer to http://plnkr.co/edit/8Wx4P71rfTCNovlfoxIH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
I would write this as below.
    'use strict';

    (function () {

        function MyService($http) {

        function getService() {

            var url = yourURL;
            return $http({ method: 'GET', cache: false, url: url });
        }

            return {
                getService: getService

            };
        }

        angular.module('app')
            .factory('MyService', MyService);
    }());

controller code:

      MyService.getService().then(function(response) {

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this `factory` just *return request response* `promise` and in *controller* use `.then` on *returned* `promise`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('MyService', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
       getData: function() {
          return $http.get('/api/endpoint');
       }
    };
}]);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', function($scope, $http, MyService){
   MyService.getData().then(function(response){
     $scope.myVarialbe = response.data;
   });
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use $q is better.

Eg:

```
app.factory('MyService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
return {
   getData: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/api/endpoint')
          .then( function(resp) {
              deferred.resolve( resp.data );
           });
      return deferred.promise;
     }
   };
}]);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyService',function($scope, MyService){
    MyService.getData().then(function(data){
        $scope.myVarialbe = data;
    })
}]);
```